# how to pass multiple variable keyword arguments in openapi

Tags: python, openapi

i have a Python based `POST` request that accepts `kwargs` (keyword arguments) based on something like `client_id`. In its implementation, we know which arguments are expected from which `client_id`. But how do i show this info in openapi?

for now what i was able to do is define a schema for a single `kwarg` like this:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  key:
    oneOf:
      - type: string
      - type: number
      - type: integer
      - type: boolean
    nullable: true
    description: Any keyword specified by the VoD publisher
    example: val
```

1. is this the right way to do or is there a better way?
2. if this is the correct way, how do i show that the API can accept multiple such `kwarg`s?